# get textView contentsize height is wrong in iOS 8

Tags: ios, textview, autolayout, ios8, contentsize

use masonry had setup textView's constraints, get `textView.contentSize.height` after `[textView layoutIfNeed]`, this value is -8

this bug is only in systemVersion less than 9.0

find a method and try:

```
[[textView layoutManager] usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer]
```

get `textView.contentSize.height` is also not right

Answer (score 1):

try this , After assigning text to textview

txtview.sizeToFit()